# Program in Python to input/output strings to/from an external exe file

Tags: python, multithreading, parallel-processing, subprocess, child-process

I am writing a program in Python to input/output strings to/from an external exe file. The flow of string input/output is as follows. (where py is the Python file, cmdx and responsex are the strings to be exchanged, and exe is the external exe file)

py→cmd1→exe

↓
py←response1←exe

↓
py→cmd2→exe

↓
py←response2←exe

↓
py→cmd3→exe

↓
py→cmd4→exe

↓
exe start calculating(This process takes some time)

↓
exe finish calculating

↓
py←response3←exe

When the string cmd4 is sent from python to exe, the exe file starts a complex calculation that consumes CPU and memory and takes a long time. The exe file does not support multiple cores of the CPU.

I would like to do this sequence of processing asynchronously from the Python file to multiple exe files. (These exe files are all copies of one exe file, and the strings sent and received for each exe file are roughly the same except for cmd3).
Ideally, when I run the Python file, multiple exe's will consume CPU and memory (two in my program example) to perform calculations in parallel.

I wrote a program like the one below that sends/receives strings between a python file and an exe file, but I cannot do that with more than one exe file. Only one exe works fine, other exes only consume memory and do not work.

How do I make the modifications so the program will work as I want it to?

```
import subprocess


def read(proc):#Read output from exe
    for line in proc.stdout:#Read output from exe line by line
        line=line.rstrip().decode('utf-8')#The output is returned as a string of bytes, so convert it to a string.
        print(line)
        if(last_response1 in line):#Judges the end of output from exe. If a line is read that contains the string last_response1 in the output, exit
            break
        if(last_response2 in line):#Judges the end of output from exe.
            break
        if(last_response3 in line):#Judges the end of output from exe.
            break

def write(proc,cmd):#Write to exe
    proc.stdin.write((cmd+'\n').encode())#Write to exe. The string must be converted to a byte string.
    proc.stdin.flush()

def end(proc):#Exit subprocess
    proc.stdin.close()
    proc.terminate()
    proc.wait(timeout=0.2)

def main():
    proc1=subprocess.Popen('external1.exe',stdin=subprocess.PIPE,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)#Open pipes in both input and output direction for exe files
    proc2=subprocess.Popen('external2.exe',stdin=subprocess.PIPE,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    write(proc1,cmd1)#Write cmd1 to exe
    read(proc1)#Wait for response from exe. response1 is returned.
    write(proc1,cmd2)#Write cmd2 to exe
    read(proc1)#Wait for response from exe. response2 is returned.
    write(proc1,cmd3)#Write cmd3 to exe

    write(proc2,cmd1)
    read(proc2)
    write(proc2,cmd2)
    read(proc2)
    write(proc2,cmd3)

    write(proc1,cmd4)#external1.exe starts caluculating
    write(proc2,cmd4)#external2.exe starts caluculating
    read(proc1)
    read(proc2)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

P.S.

Thank you all for the detailed information on how to solve this problem.
In my case, it seems that subprocess.Popen by itself cannot solve the problem, and need to use multithreading or multiprocessing.

But I have some questoins.
The first question is whether I should use multithreading or multiprocessing.
The exe does CPU-bound processing and the python file spends the most time waiting for the exe to process.Therefore I thought I should use multiprocessing, is that correct?

Another question is, there are several standard modules for multithreading and multiprocessing, which one is better?
For multithreading, there are "threading", "concurrent.futures", etc., while for multiprocessing, there are "multiprocessing", "concurrent.futures", etc.
(I tried to use concurrent.futures, but I don't know how to use a subprocess.Popen object as an argument to the prepared function when using the executor.submit() )

Comment: Turn your code above into a `class` and write some multiprocessing ( https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html ) code around it. In the main process create a `for` loop that instantiates an instance of that class in each iteration, then `.join` on them all once completed. Once that works, implement high level control behavior of the individual processes. // Be wary, research the Python Global Interpreter Lock (Python GIL) and how this will effect your intended behavior.

Comment: You can use multithreading (or asyncio) and have each thread manage communication with one process. The GIL shouldn't be a problem here, it is usually released while processing blocking IO.

Comment: Define a single function that does a single run of the external exe file. Make a multiprocessing pool, and submit/map as many jobs as you like to that pool, each calling that function with potentially different parameters.

Comment: Thank you all for the detailed information on how to solve this problem. 
I have added a few more questions to my original post. Would you please take the time to read them?